# Google Chrome - Disable Network Connection

Tags: google-chrome, internet-connection

Using Google Chrome, is it possible to "Work Offline", that is, disable the network connection.  I'm looking for the same feature that is included in Firefox 4.x under the File menu called Work Offline.  This feature will assist in testing a HTML 5 cache manifest.

Comment: I don't thinks so. But for cache concerns could this help you: chrome://net-internals/ ?

Comment: Wonder if setting a proxy server to 127.0.0.1 under proxy settings will help you simulate loss of network connectivity.

Comment: Look at this solution: [enter link description here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32607960/5721199)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's not. Some Google services will work online (Gmail for one), but that doesn't exactly help you. You can open a local file with Ctrl-O but again, this doesn't really help you.

Answer (score 21):

At least with 47.0.2526.80, Chrome Developer tools have a Network Throttling preset option Offline.

[image]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>